# How do I possibly fix a blurry background image

Tags: html, css

So why is it when I insert my back ground image for my website, it gets blurry and makes the image look worse than it initially was when I did not stretch it out to cover the page here is the  element code.

```
 <style type="text/css">
      body {
          margin-left: 15%;
          margin-right: 15%;
          border:10px dotted black;
          padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
          font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
          background-image:url(nope.jpg.jpg);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-attachment: fixed;
          background-size: cover;
          image-rendering: pixelated;
          background-size: 1500px 1000px;
      }
    </style>
```

I am a newbie programmer so is it possibly because the image was initially to small it had a dimension of 300px,150px which did not fit the page so I stretched it out and now it fits the page but it is blurred. Are there any specific code to fix this problem or do I have to find another image?

Comment: You would need a bigger image

Comment: You can't increase the quality of a small image like that...

Comment: Hmm okay let me try looking for a bigger image because most of the images I find online usually have the same dimensions are there any specific websites you recommend where I can find good images with large dimensions.

Comment: If you want to experiment with different dimension images then Lorem Picsum [link]https://picsum.photos/ might help. It's specifically for placeholder type photos in the same way as lorem ipsum is used as placceholder text.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is probably too small for the viewport. You have to find an image that is high definition and pretty large. It's a good idea, for when picking a background image, to find one that is **too** big for the website, that way, it works for all devices.

Also it would have been helpful if you provided the image that you used, that way I could see the actual problem instead of just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Background-size: cover
```

will make any image stretch to the size of the positioning area. If you want the image to be the entire background of your website, you need a higher quality image with a higher pixel count.

Comment: Hey thanks, do you know any websites where I can find good, large quality images because most of the images I find online are usually the same thing. Thanks

Comment: I really love https://unsplash.com -- lots of hi-res backgrounds, all under the Creative Commons license as well :)

Please upvote if you can for the rep :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying to upvote but it says I need 15 rep I am new here but will try to gain the rep so I can upvote this.